# How to combine two lists and it will be a sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
list1 = ['name', 'age', 'address']
list2 = ['mega', '20', 'Sadia']
```

**expected output:**

```
['namemega', 'age20', 'addressSadia']
```

Comment: You can easily do this using `zip` in a list comprehension, but don't you rather want to have a dict or at least a list of tuples? That format does not seem very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip`, as below:

```
list3 = [a + b for a, b in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip` and `list comprehension`:

```
In [1968]: list3 = [x + y for x,y in zip(list1, list2)]

In [1968]: list3
Out[1968]: ['namemega', 'age20', 'addressSadia']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are unfamiliar with zip there is an easy method for you, you can Use this code, It will generate your expected output

```
list1 = ['name', 'age', 'address']
list2 = ['mega', '20', 'Sadia']
list3 = []

for i in range(0,len(list1)):
  list3.append(list1[i]+list2[i]) # Concatenation
list3
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers already explain how to get your desired output. However, I would argue that this is not the output you actually *need*. You will have to separate the key (e.g. `name`) from the value (e.g. `mega) each time, and by joining the strings without any separator, you will have to *know* which key was used in order to separate the key!

Instead, you could just create a list of tuples, either using a list comprehension or just builtin functions. This way, you can easily iterate and separate the keys and values in the list.

```
>>> [(a, b) for a, b in zip(list1, list2)]
[('name', 'mega'), ('age', '20'), ('address', 'Sadia')]
>>> list(zip(list1, list2))
[('name', 'mega'), ('age', '20'), ('address', 'Sadia')]
```

More useful, though, might be a dictionary, which, on top of that, will also allow you to easily get the value for a specific key, using e.g. `d["name"]`; again, you can use a dict comprehension or builtin functions:

```
>>> {a: b for a, b in zip(list1, list2)}
{'name': 'mega', 'age': '20', 'address': 'Sadia'}
>>> dict(zip(list1, list2))
{'name': 'mega', 'age': '20', 'address': 'Sadia'}
```

You might even consider creating a `namedtuple` to create a sort-of data class. This does not only add a bit of type-safety, but also allows to get values using dot-notation, like `person.name`.

```
>>> import collections
>>> Person = collections.namedtuple("Person", "name age address")
>>> Person(*list2)
Person(name='mega', age='20', address='Sadia')
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are familiar with pandas, you can easily add two dataframes to create a result for you. try this.

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame(data = ['name', 'age', 'address'])
b = pd.DataFrame(data = ['mega', '20', 'Sadia'])
c = a + b
print (list(c[0]))
```